# Why does my refs/remotes/origin not have a ref to master?

Tags: git

In the process of exploring the inner working of Git, I went in to the refs/remotes/origin directory of my git project and ran the `ls` command. Here is what I see.

```
$ ls
HEAD  sp2013dev
```

Then I ran `cat HEAD` and here's what was printed.

```
$ cat HEAD
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

However, there is no file or directory by the name of master in the refs/remotes/origin directory. This directory only has 'HEAD' and 'sp2013dev'

Am I missing something here ? Why is HEAD referring to something (btw, is 'ref' the correct terminology for this 'something' ?) which does not exist ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just for emphasis: you're poking around in the insides of git; you've found a directory named `.git/refs/remotes/origin` and it contains two files, `HEAD` and `sp2013dev`.  The contents of `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` are `ref: refs/remotes/origin/master`.

A reference that consists of the literal string `ref:` followed by another reference name is a "symbolic" reference, in git terms.  It means "although this is a valid name, the SHA-1 to which this reference resolves is found by reading another reference."  But, as you note, there's no *file* named `master` in the `.git/refs/remotes/origin` directory, so you are wondering how this can work.

The answer is that not all references are necessarily in files.  References can be, and are, "packed".  Currently, packed references are found in `.git/packed-refs`, which is a plain-text file.  Your own Git will have a `refs/remotes/origin/master` paired with an SHA-1 hash in your `.git/packed-refs`.

Note: a ref may appear in both the `packed-refs` file *and* a file in a `.git/refs` sub-directory.  In this case, the second version overrides the first.  This allows `git pack-refs` (invoked by `git gc`) to pack all refs, and then let refs become "unpacked" as needed, when they're updated.  (But this is an implementation detail, and you're not supposed to *assume* this; in scripts, use `git update-ref` and `git symbolic-ref` to read and update references, and let those programs enforce the updating rules.)

Currently, it appears that there is no packed format for symbolic references, so those all live in "real files" for now.

#### Long aside: how this all works (read only if sufficiently curious)

When you clone another repository—or, for that matter, any time you run `git fetch` or `git push`, although those do not deal with `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`—there are *two* repositories involved, with two sets of rules being enforced by two different Gits controlling those two repositories.  Aside from the command `git remote set-head`, it's only `git clone` that creates the `origin/HEAD` in the first place, so we can concentrate on `git clone` itself.

Since there are two repositories, let's give them names.  We can call your local repository *L* and the repository at `origin`, which you're in the process of cloning, *O*.  Since *O* *is* a Git repository, it has its own `HEAD`.  This `HEAD` is normally a symbolic reference: `HEAD -> master` for instance.  Whatever branch it names, though, is local to *O*: it's `refs/heads/branch`, which is a local branch on *O*.  If you were to log in on the machine hosting repository *O*, and view their `.git/HEAD` file, it would contain `ref: refs/heads/branch`.  The Git on *O* is enforcing this rule, that `HEAD` always names a local (local-to-*O* that is) branch.

Now, your own Git, running locally on your system, is working to create repository *L*.  Your Git on *L* wants to create, on `L`, a remote-tracking branch whose full name is `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.  This is going to be a symbolic ref, and it is going to point to `refs/remotes/origin/branch`.  But there are two complications:

1. Your Git, on *L*, must find or figure out their Git's (on *O*) symbolic `HEAD`.  In our case it's (their) `refs/heads/branch`.
2. Your Git, on *L*, must then *create* `refs/remotes/origin/branch` as a remote-tracking branch.  (Your Git will store this in your `.git/packed-refs` file.)  Your Git then creates *L*'s `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` as a symbolic reference to `refs/remotes/origin/branch`.

Something can go wrong at either of these two points.  Step 2 fails if you use `git clone -b otherbranch --single-branch`, for instance.  You are telling your Git that *L* should not have `refs/remotes/origin/branch` at all, but only `refs/remotes/origin/otherbranch`.  But if step 2 fails like this, your Git simply does not create `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` at all.  That way you won't have, in *L*, a `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` pointing to the non-existent remote-tracking branch.

Step 1 "fails" (in a way) if either your Git, building *L*, or their Git, serving *O* to your Git, is too old.  There is a defined protocol for looking up reference names during these Internet-connection "phone calls" that copy commits (`git fetch`, `git push`) and view branch and tag names (`git ls-remote`) and so on.  The `clone` command uses the same defined protocol.  Early in the connection, your Git and their Git negotiate the protocol options to use.  Older Gits have no option for expressing and resolving a symbolic reference, so if either Git does not support the option, *O* just claims that *O*'s `HEAD` is some particular SHA-1 ID.  The Git building the clone *L* has to *guess* which branch is actually `HEAD` on *O*.  It does so by scanning through the *rest* of the branch names it gets for *O*.  If *O*'s `HEAD` is `1234567`, and there's one branch that is also `1234567`, well, that must be where their `HEAD` points!

This can be *wrong*, i.e., your Git may guess wrong.  But if so, your Git just proceeds with the wrong assumption and goes on to worry about step 2.

Step 1 can fail quite differently if their (*O*'s) `HEAD` is detached.  In this case, there may be no matching branch.  If so, your Git won't guess wrong, it will just know that there's no branch checked out in repository *O*.  If both your Git and their Git are not too old, your Git will negotiate the right protocol option and your Git will know for sure whether *O* has a detached HEAD, and if not, what branch is checked out in *O*.

It's easy to make step 2 fail deliberately: just clone some repository whose `HEAD` you know refers to some particular branch (such as `master`) while using both `--single-branch` and `-b` to make your clone *L* *avoid* that branch.  It's a bit harder to make step 1 fail deliberately, but you can do it by logging in on the system that exports *O* and detaching *O*'s HEAD.

If you do this, though, then—back on your own system—use `git clone` to make *L*, you simply find that your clone *L* has *no* `origin/HEAD`.  This maintains the normal rules, which include these three (I'm not sure off-hand if there are more):

1. All ordinary (non-symbolic) references contain a valid hash ID.
2. All symbolic references (with one special case exception detailed below) contain the name of an existing reference.
3. The special reference `HEAD`, which is normally (but not always) symbolic, contains only a reference to a *local* branch, i.e., a name in the `refs/heads/` name-space.

The special case exception is that the special reference name `HEAD` *may* contain the name of a local branch that does not actually exist yet.  This (called, variously, an "unborn branch" or an "orphan branch") is how `master` comes into being in a new, empty repository: `HEAD` points to `master` even though `master` does not yet exist.  A commit you make when in this state causes the branch to begin existing, pointing to the commit just made; and the commit just made has *no* parents, i.e., is a root commit.

You might think you could break these rules using `git remote set-head`, but in fact, it won't let you:

> Use `<branch>` to set the symbolic-ref `refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD`
>    explicitly. e.g., "git remote set-head origin master" will set the
>    symbolic-ref `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` to
>    `refs/remotes/origin/master`. **This will only work if
>    `refs/remotes/origin/master` already exists; if not it must be
>    fetched first.**

(emphasis mine).  For more about `git remote set-head`, see [the `git remote` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).

You *can* break these rules using either direct access to the `.git` directory, or with `git symbolic-ref`.  Obviously, if you poke around inside `.git`, you can [mess things up pretty good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights), :-) so that requires care.  The sharp edges with `git symbolic-ref` are a bit more surprising, but now you know that you must be careful with that, too.

Comment: Isn't there a much simpler explanation? Namely that the fetched `HEAD` on the `origin` remote is pointing to a *remote* branch named `master` which the OP has not fetched?

Comment: @jpaugh: No—or at least not normally—because the local HEAD is not allowed to point to anything but a local branch name, or a commit. (It's possible to break this by writing the file yourself, but Git internally won't let you get "on" a remote-tracking branch: you get a detached HEAD, with HEAD containing a raw hash ID, instead.) But it *is* completely normal for a remote-tracking `HEAD` to be a symbolic ref to a remote-tracking `origin/master` while the remote-tracking `origin/master` is packed.

Comment: We're not talking about `HEAD` here, but `remotes/origin/HEAD`.  (Sorry to bring you into an old thread.) Thus, the second part of your comment seems to confirm my suspicion, namely that the remote `HEAD` is pointing to a branch which has not been fetched locally yet, right?

Comment: @jpaugh: I've deleted two long-ish comments and replaced them with this one. I know what you mean, but it's wrong: see the new "Long aside" section. Note particularly "step 2": your Git creates `origin/HEAD`, but *only if it also creates the corresponding remote-tracking branch*.