# Not able to clone a git repo

Tags: git

While clone a git repo I am facing the below fatal error.

```
fatal: cannot process 'refs/remotes/origin/rr' and 'refs/remotes/origin/rr/ee' at the same time
```

This rep is hosted in AWS and I am using this repo for more then a year. Last 2 days I am not able to clone this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my refs/remotes/origin not have a ref to master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855567/why-does-my-refs-remotes-origin-not-have-a-ref-to-master)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways for Git to write a reference onto disk: as a file in the file system, and as an entry in the packed-refs file.

When you write a reference into the file system, you can't have both `refs/remotes/origin/r2` (because that would be a file) and `refs/remotes/origin/r2/qe` (because that would make `r2` a directory). Obviously, `r2` cannot be both a file and a directory at the same time, so Git fails.

If the server has both of these references, they're probably in the `packed-refs` file, which is used to refer to references whose objects are all packed. This is more efficient than storing large numbers of unchanged references in the file system, so Git updates this file when it packs the repository. It also doesn't suffer from the file-directory problem that's mentioned above, although it's not possible to use this file in all cases.

If you're just trying to do a fetch and not a full clone, you probably want to do a `git fetch --prune origin` first to remove the branch that isn't on the server.

If you're explicitly trying to clone both branches, you need to skip specifying both, because it won't be possible. If you're having this problem with a repository, it's probably best to notify the person maintaining that repository and ask them to delete one of those references, since it will cause problems for anyone who tries to clone.

If you can't do that, you can clone with `git clone --single-branch -b master origin` to clone only the `master` branch (or whichever branch you like) of your `origin` remote, and then pull in other branches as you need them with `git fetch`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge