# What character encoding is used in Git symbolic refs (especially on Windows)?

Tags: windows, git, character-encoding, filesystems, symbolic-references

This is a really quick question: what is the character encoding used in symbolic ref files like `.git/HEAD`, especially on Windows?

Is it the same as the filesystem's encoding? It sounds improbable, though, since I've heard before that Windows' filesystem encoding is UTF-16 and ASCII control bytes `0x00..0x1F` and `0x7F` is prohibited in Git ref name (we can't have a byte 0x00 in Git ref). Is it UTF-8 universally? However it does not seem to be documented in `git help check-ref-format`. Maybe it lies somewhere else? Or is symbolic ref's encoding undefined? However then, how can we clone, push and fetch branches between each other?

Comment: I'm sure it's ASCII sans ASCII control characters.

Comment: However then, why doesn't `git help check-ref-format` prohibit `0x80..0xFF`?

Comment: You are not supposed to open and read these files directly. You are supposed to run `git symbolic-ref` instead. Use whatever encoding `git symbolic-ref` uses as its input and output, and don't worry about what encoding might appear in a Git internal file, because that encoding might change tomorrow.

Comment: Note that push and fetch cannot handle symbolic refs in general. There is one special case for `HEAD`, handled by `git clone` and `git remote set-head`, in an undocumented fashion (it's full of historical oddities, nobody wants to describe them in anything official :-) ). Don't try to transfer symbolic refs from one repository to another; it doesn't work in general.

Comment: @torek Thanks. However, um... in fact, what matters is the path name of the ref file that `HEAD` points to. We want to automatically add that ref file to the dependency set of incrementally-compilable program that shows the commit hash on `--version`.

Comment: Side note: when references are [packed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22855803/7976758) there is no "ref file". Use `git symbolic-ref` to poke around and `git update-ref` to mess with references.

Comment: Don't trust it to *be* a path name; as @phd notes, sometimes it isn't. The upcoming ref-table project will remove all of these files, except perhaps for `HEAD` itself, in favor of a real (if somewhat oddly encoded) refs database.

Comment: We don't. The Haskell package `githash` adds the git information on the compile-time. Since the Haskell compiler GHC only recompiles the updated files, we need to tell GHC that Git-related files should be considered as dependency. So the matter is always best-effort; all we do is add the related ref files that already exist as dependency. we shouldn't do as much as `git update-ref $(git symbolic-ref HEAD) $(git rev-parse HEAD)`. ref-table project sounds like blessing; we only need to add that table file as dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific character encoding used by Git's refs.  The format is specified in the `git check-ref-format` manual page, and it allows a variety of byte values, including values which are not value UTF-8, such as 0xFE and 0xFF.

However, having said that, it is customary to use UTF-8 for ref names, and when ref files are written into the file system on Windows, they will be converted into UTF-16 because Windows can't handle anything else in its file system.  The contents of the files, however, remains something containing arbitrary bytes, which, again, are customarily (but need not be) UTF-8.