# Installing Julia Packages via GitHub

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, julia, git-clone

To preface this question I am coming from the perspective of an absolute beginner, trying to learn Julia. I was recommended to try the SciML tutorial and in trying to install it have fallen at the first hurdle.

So far I have:

- Installed Julia
- Installed Anaconda
- Installed Jupyter Notebook
- Added "git" through the Anaconda console
- Added "IJulia"

From here I have been able to open Jupyter through Anaconda and access Julia 1.7.3 within it. Following this I attempted to follow the instructions on the SciML website for getting started with the tutorial, which is to enter this code:

```
using Pkg
pkg"add https://github.com/SciML/SciMLTutorials.jl"
using SciMLTutorials
SciMLTutorials.open_notebooks()
```

However, the second line is throwing this error

```
invalid git HEAD (reference 'refs/heads/master' not found)
```

I have also tried installing the package through the Julia console, but recieve the same error.

I am at a loss of how to proceed - I can't find anything in the documentation that suggests why this may be or how to proceed - since I am so new to this I suspect I may have missed a step in my installation process, but can't figure out where that may be.

Comment: That's pretty weird. Can you post the complete output of the second line? Also, the version of git you have installed - it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22855803/8127) like one possible cause of this issue is if the Git version you have is too old.

Comment: For the record, I'm able to add the package successfully with no problems. In addition to the above, please also mention what your OS is, whether you're able to install other packages, and whether you have any unusual circumstances that might interfere e.g. a corporate or other firewall, disk issues, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, I managed to get it to work by trying 'Pkg.add("SciMLTutorial")' instead and no longer have the error. If you are still interested in the issue I can try and recreate it, however, my issue is resolved.

Comment: I'm mildly curious how this happens, but not enough to dig deeper when you have a working solution already. There's probably going to be someone else with the same problem in a year or two, who stumbles upon this thread and asks for help... We'll get to the bottom of it then! :) Good luck with your Julia journey.